# Como mostrar todos los registros en SQL que cumplan con la condición de que sean todos los valores de la lista

Tags: sql, select

Supongamos que tengo una tabla de personas que viajaron a varios destinos, como hago para mostrar los nombres de las personas que viajaron a dos destinos en una lista ejemplo ('Brasil','Uruguay') pero que cumpla la condición que viajo a esos dos lugares no que haya sido alguno

```
  cod | nombre | pais_destino  |
 |----|--------|---------------|
 |  1 | Walter |  Panamá       |
 |-------------|---------------|
 |  2 | Roberto|  Uruguay      |               
 |-------------|---------------|
 |  3 | Pablo  |  Uruguay      |
 |-------------|---------------|
 |  4 | Pablo  |  Brasil       |
 |-------------|---------------|
```

si uso
select nombre from tabla1 where pais_destino in('Brasil',Uruguay')

me devuelve los registros con el nombre Pablo (ignorando duplicados) y el de Roberto siendo que solamente quiero mostrar en este simple ejemplo el de Pablo que es el que viajo a TODOS los paises de esa lista y NO a UNO de los que la integran, hay alguna manera de resolver eso?

Comment: Sobre que base de datos? deberias usar la clausula ALL...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto te puede servir:

```
 SELECT nombre from @T where pais_destino in('Brasil','Uruguay')
 GROUP BY nombre
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Saludos

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe brevemente el funcionamiento de la consulta. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código. Lee [answer]. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._